# Mostrar el nombre ingresado en una Activity a un Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Cordial saludo, tengo un inconveniente con el desarrollo de una app, quiero que el usuario ingrese el nombre en un MainActivity, y su nombre se vea reflejado en un Fragment que se encuentra dentro de un elemento de NavigationDrawer. Agradeciendo mucho su colaboración.
****MainActivity.****

```
package com.compuoriente.usuario.ejercicioprueba;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Ingresar;
    EditText enviar_nombre;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ingresar);
        enviar_nombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enviar_nombre);
        Ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Ingresar = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                Ingresar.putExtra("Envio",enviar_nombre.getText().toString());
                startActivity(Ingresar);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
package com.compuoriente.usuario.ejercicioprueba;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link InicioFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link InicioFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public InicioFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment InicioFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static InicioFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        InicioFragment fragment = new InicioFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: En que activity muestras el InicioFragment ?

Comment: No estas cargando ningún Fragment desde la Activity mencionada, como cargas el fragment? Revisa por favor [ask] y modifica tu pregunta para que obtengas la ayuda deseada en el sitio,saludos.

Comment: el InicioFragment lo muestro en el NavigationDrawer que se enlaza al InicioFragment que se muestra desde un prinicipio